# require_once() is blocked by open_basedir - then how to make system safe?

Tags: php, passwords, require-once, open-basedir

I have a website with a lot of important data and care about security, and now I must run there some potentially unsafe code (Joomla). I want to "enclose" this whole directory tree by open_basedir, and at the same time I wan't to hide database password from it - so I want to move the database password OUT of the open_basedir tree (along with some functionality which would connect to the database, so that the caller doesn't get the password itself). But there is a problem - require_once also doesn't work when open_basedir is in action!!!

Is there any way how to set up open_basedir and allow require_once?

Is there any other way how to call some SECRET php code OUT of the open_basedir limited area?

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> require_once also doesn't work when open_basedir is in action

Yes it does, unless you're trying to include a file *outside* of the basedir.  Then it'd fail like anything else that tries to reach outside of the basedir.

> Is there any other way how to call some SECRET php code OUT of the open_basedir limited area?

There is no way out of a basedir if you have it defined.  If you find one, it is a bug and must be squashed immediately.